# Excel VBA Getting run time error 91 for 4 digit numbers

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code:

```
Sub MaxNumberRow()
Dim max As Double
Dim rowNum As Long

With Sheet1
    max = WorksheetFunction.max(.Columns(1))

    If max > 0 Then
        rowNum = .Columns(1).Find(What:=max, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rowNum, 1)).Select
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

But I am getting a **run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.**

Getting error when I am finding 4 digit max number.

Please Help....

Thanks in advance

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: The problem is the `Find` as it only look at the visible cell content. So if the `max` is 1234.123456789 but the cell shows only 1234.123457, then `Find` will not find the `max`. Try the `WorksheetFunction.Match` approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the Cells are relative to the current sheet. Try this instead:

```
Sub MaxNumberRow()
  Dim max As Double
  Dim rowNum As Long

  With Sheet1
      max = WorksheetFunction.max(.Columns(1))
      If max > 0 Then
        rowNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(max, .Columns(1), 0)
        .Columns(1).Resize(rowNum).Select
      End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To have it work, I had to 
    - Reference directly "Sheet1" within the current workbook
    - address the `Range`and the `Cells` in the `with` domain (with prefixing `.`)

What do you get with the code below?:

```
Sub MaxNumberRow()
    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap
Dim max As Double
Dim rowNum As Long


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 1)).Select
    max = WorksheetFunction.max(.Columns(1))
    If max > 0 Then
        rowNum = .Columns(1).Find(What:=max, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rowNum, 1)).Select
    End If
End With
Exit Sub

ErrorTrap:
    Beep
    MsgBox "FAILED" & Chr(13) & _
                    "arg: " & rowNum & Chr(13) & _
                    "Error number: " & Err & Chr(13) & _
                    Error(Err)
End Sub
```